# What kind of databases are used on the cloud and what are the concepts behind?

Tags: database, nosql, cloud

I was reading this [article](http://www.theserverside.com/feature/Developing-for-the-Cloud-How-Developing-in-the-Cloud-is-Different) . And the guy mentioned "Relational databases are no longer the norm in the cloud." What does he mean by that? If Relational databases are not used what kind of databases are we going to use and what is the concept behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link to your article is missing.  However, I suspect that the author is referring to various forms of "[NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)" dbs, such as key-value stores, document-based databases, object-based databases, and various other technologies.  The main advantage of this approach is that full relational capabilities of a RDBMS are not always needed, and if you discard them, you can sometimes improve performance and scalability.

For example, Amazon offers the Amazon [Simple DB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/), which is basically a giant distributed dictionary with a nicer query language.

I could go on, but I suspect a few searches for NoSQL would be more useful than anything I could write.